# statistical method for finding significant numbers in a set

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, population, set-theory

Suppose that we have a population of $N= 1000$ people and they want to select 5 items (for simplicity) $\{A, B, C, D, E\}$ (but actually number of items is in the order of thousands). Number of selections for items is $\{3, 142, 52, 633, 800\}$. Each person (selector) is free to select as many items as they want. Selecting of one item may affect for selection of another item by one person. For example, if items are goods in a supermarket, the first person may select items $A$ and $C$. The second person may select all items. We want to find “the minimum number of selections”, named $T$, so that if number of selections for an item is larger than $T$, we can say that item is interesting or popular for the population since at least $T$ people have selected that item. We want to find this number ($T$) by “a statistical method”.

As an another example, for each item, we can assign a value to it by the percentage of people who have selected that item. So, we have a range of 0 (no person has selected it) to 100% (all people have selected that item). Definitely, 100% means popularity or significance for that item for the population. But We want to find what is the minimum percentage so that we can say that item is still popular. In other words, is the range of popularity from 20-100% or 10-100% or ....? We want to find a statistical measure for defining popularity of significance.

Thanks.

Comment: No. Depending on your context, what is "important" would be very different.

Comment: we want to find important based on a statistical test.

Comment: Use the following rule: $$\text{a number $x_i$ is significant if $x_i=42$}$$

Comment: Can a person select more than 1 of the same item? Say pick A two times?

Comment: No. Each person can select each item just once.

Comment: This question is unanswerable because it needs a definition or quantitative description of what you might mean by "interesting or popular."

Answer (score 6):

Your question is circular. You say you want to use a test find the 'important' values. And when asked what you mean by 'important' you say the 'important' values are ones that pass the test.

To make sense of this it might be most useful for you to look at numerical or graphical summaries of your data.
Then from the summaries try to get an intuitive view of what *you* mean by 'important'.
That might lead you to your own general criterion for importance. (Opinions of others may differ.)

Using R statistical software:

```
x =  c(3 , 4 , 52 , 633 , 1000, 0, 6915 , 890 , 500)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
     0       4     500    1111     890    6915 
sd(x)
[1] 2212.417  # sample standard deviation
```

The mean and median are two ways of describing the center of the data.
The **mean** (average) would be the balance point if you consider the values
plotted along a line, giving each equal weight (red line below). Are the
below-average values important because they are "more typical" or is the largest value important because it has such a large influence on the mean?

```
stripchart(x, pch=20)
 abline(v = mean(x), col="red")
```

[image]

The **median** is the middle
value, if the observations are sorted (halfway between the two middle values
if the sample size is even). Here the middle value of the sorted data is $500.$

```
sort(x)
[1]    0    3    4   52  500  633  890 1000 6915
```

In a boxplot, the box shows the extent of the middle half of the data (from the first to third quartile in the summary). The median is at the line within the box. So-called "whiskers" may extend partway to the minimum or maximum, but the most extreme values might be
plotted separately. Because the plot extends so far to the right to include the maximum value the scale doesn't show much detail for the values around $0.$

Which is more 'important' to you--the half of the values inside the box or the half outside the box?
Some people might think that the maximum value $5915$ is the only really 'important' one, and
some might think it should be disregarded entirely because it is so much different from the others--not typical, perhaps some sort of mistake.

```
boxplot(x, col="skyblue2", pch=20, horizontal=T)
```

There are many possible numerical and graphical descriptions of data because different situations make it appropriate to focus on different values as being 'important'.

[image]

---

*Addedum* per Comments: Suppose there are Five categories of items and 1000 subjects, each of whom is asked to choose 2 favorites. Then you might say each of the five
counts is roughly distributed as $\mathsf{Binom}(n=1000, p=2/5),$ in which case one would expect 95% of counts to be between 370 and 430 inclusive. So any item with
less than 370 'votes' might be considered 'unpopular' and and any item with more than 430 might be considered 'popular'.

However, the vector of counts
$(360, 420, 402, 398, 411),$ even with one slightly 'unpopular' count, would
not be enough evidence to say that categories are of 'significantly' unequal popularity overall at the 5% level of significance (P-value is $0.066 > 0.05.)$

```
sum(dbinom(370:430, 1000, 2/5))
[1] 0.9510791

prop.test(c(360,420,402,398,411), rep(1000,5))

        5-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(360, 420, 402, 398, 411) out of rep(1000, 5)
X-squared = 8.8167, df = 4, p-value = 0.06585
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 prop 3 prop 4 prop 5 
 0.360  0.420  0.402  0.398  0.411
```

If you think something similar to this approach may be useful, please edit your question
with enough specific information that one of us might follow up usefully.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Let me clarify my mean by importance. Suppose that a population (N= 1000) want to select some items {A ,B ,C ,D ,E ,F ,G, H, K, L} . Item A is selected by 3 people, item  by 4 people and ..... Cont.

Comment: Now we want to find which items are not important for the people (or which items are important) based on a statistical test. Definitely item  E is important since all people have selected it. Can we say C is important for the population (52 people have selected that)? In other words, what is the T so that if number of selectors for an  item is larger than T, we can say that item is important for the population and if it is less than T, that item is not important (or interesting) for that population.

Comment: Suggest you 1) Edit your Question with that explanation [Not everyone reads Comments.]  2) **Clarify your counts:** there seem to be some typos there. 3) Give some idea what you mean by important: Letter chosen by more than half? Letter chosen by more than avg nr, of subjects? Enough difference in numbers of choices to show not all equally popular? 4) Make rules for subjects clear: Can subjects choose as many as they like? Limit of say 5 per subject? // Any clue about what you are doing and what your purpose is might be helpful.// See my Addendum. But others may have useful answers.

Comment: @BrucET Thanks for your comments. I posted the edited question in a news post:    https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/492958/statistical-method-for-finding-minimum-numbers-of-selections-for-popularity-of-a

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data to place the orders in a contingency table then you can compute conditional probabilities of selecting the other items. Based on that you can make decision rules to add the items to the list.

For instance a hypothetical table, showing the frequency of items being bought together (where X means that the item is bought without another item) could be:

```
    A    B    C    D    E    X
A   0    0    0    3    0    0     3
B   0    0    10   2    100  30    142 
C   0    10   0    0    30   12    52
D   3    2    0    0    422  206   633
E   0    100  30   422  0    248   800
X   0    30   12   206  248  0
    3    142  52   633  800
```

The decision rules are not easy to determine. You might select the items with the highest frequencies, or you could select the items which have highest positive correlation (items for which the conditional frequency is higher than the non-conditional frequency).

For example let's compare the frequency of selections dependent on having already selecting D

$$\begin{array}{}
& A & B & C & D & E \\
\text{conditional on D} & \frac{3}{633}& \frac{2}{633}& \frac{0}{633}& \frac{0}{633}& \frac{422}{633}\\
\text{unconditional} & \frac{3}{1000} & \frac{142}{1000} & \frac{52}{1000} & \frac{633}{1000} & \frac{800}{1000}
\end{array}$$

So somebody that has selected item D is likely gonna buy item E as well (probability 2/3), but this probability is *lower* than the unconditional probability (4/5). So while this item E has the highest probability conditional on item D, the item D is actually reducing the probability of buying item E.

On the other hand, the item A has only very low probability of being bought (1/211), but it is *higher* than the even more low unconditional probability (3/1000).

Which items you should place in the list, on what basis/grounds, is unclear. The question does not specify this clearly. The question sounds like related to a webshop which provides suggestions based on the contents of the current shopping car. In that case the underlying goal is probably *more* sales. Suggesting items that are more likely to be bought is not necessarily generating more sales. These items might already get sold without being suggested. What is needed is suggesting items that are more likely to be sold when they are suggested in comparison to not being suggested. For this you'd need to do some experimentation like [A/B-testing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing).