# Statistical method for finding minimum numbers of selections for popularity of an item

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Suppose that we have a population of N= 1000 people and they want to select 5 items (for simplicity) {A, B, C, D, E} (but actually the number of items is in the order of thousands). Number of selections for items is {3, 142, 52, 633, 800}. Each person (selector) is free to select as many items as they want. Selecting one item may affect the selection of another item by one person. For example, if items are goods in a supermarket, the first person may select items A and C. The second person may select all items. Each person can select each item just once. We want to find “the minimum number of selections”, named T, so that if the number of selections for an item is larger than T, we can say that item is interesting or popular for the population since at least T people have selected that item. We want to find this number (T) by “a statistical method”. Thanks.